# Image over image with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So, I want to put image over image. The second to be in up corner.
I want to do that with jQuery.

```
$("#result").on({
mouseenter:function(){

$("#article").attr("src", "button2.png");  

 }, ".button");
 });
```

I want when someone hovers to article to show image for SHOW MORE

Comment: you will need 2 img tags and then use css to overlay one ontop of the other

Comment: If I'm correct, you could probably do that with pure CSS using `:hover` and child selectors, which should be much more efficient. You could position the image using absolute/relative positioning I believe.

Comment: What's your HTML look like?

Comment: I don't use hover func in jQuery. I'm using 'on'. <div id="result">
<img class="button" id="article-222" src="image.jpg">
<img class="button" id="article-212" src="image.jpg">
<img class="button" id="article-292" src="image.jpg">
</div>

Comment: It would be so much more efficient to handle this with CSS as @BrandonAnzaldi stated

Answer (score 2):

Like everyone else is saying, you can do it with just CSS. The easiest way to do it I think is to have one image as a background and then just having another image on top:

See **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29om933w/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="image1">
    <img src="http://icdn4.digitaltrends.com/image/microsoft_xp_bliss_desktop_image-650x0.jpg" class="image2"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image1 {
    width: 650px;
    height: 433px;
    background: url("http://icdn4.digitaltrends.com/image/microsoft_xp_bliss_desktop_image-650x0.jpg");
}
.image1:hover .image2 {
    display: block;
}
.image2 {
    display: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

**==== ALTERNATE SOLUTION ====**

If you have to do it with `img` tags you can use the following:

See **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29om933w/1/)**

HTML:

```
<img src="http://icdn4.digitaltrends.com/image/microsoft_xp_bliss_desktop_image-650x0.jpg" class="image1"/>
<img src="http://icdn4.digitaltrends.com/image/microsoft_xp_bliss_desktop_image-650x0.jpg" class="image2"/>
```

CSS:

```
.image1 {
    position: absolute;
}
.image1:hover + .image2 {
    display: block;
}
.image2 {
    display: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}
```